# How can I make TensorFlow RNN training more robust?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am training an RNN on a time series. I subclassed `RNNCell` and I use it in `dynamic_rnn`. The topology of the `RNNCell` is as follows:

1. input (shape `[15, 100, 3]`)
2. 1x3 convolution (5 kernels), ReLu (shape `[15, 98, 5]`)
3. 1x(remaining) convolution (20 kernels), ReLu (shape `[15, 1, 20]`)
4. concatenate previous output (shape `[15, 1, 21]`)
5. squeeze and 1x1 convolution (1 kernel), ReLu (shape `[15, 1]`)
6. squeeze and softmax (shape `[15]`)

The batch size for `dynamic_rnn` is around 100 (not the same 100 of the description above, that's the number of time periods in a window of data). Epochs are made of about 200 batches.
I would like to experiment with hyperparameters and regularization, but too often what I try stops the learning entirely and I don't understand why. These are some of the weird things that happen:

- Adagrad works, but if I use Adam or Nadam the gradients are all zero.
- I am forced to set a huge learning rate (~1.0) to see learning from epoch to epoch.
- If I try to add dropout after any of the convolutions, even if I set keep_prob to 1.0 it stops learning.
- If I tweak the number of kernels in the convolutions, for some choices that would seem just as good (e.g. 5, 25, 1 vs 5, 20, 1) again the network stops learning entirely.

Why is this model so fragile? Is it the topology of the `RNNCell`?

EDIT:
This is the code of the `RNNCell`:

```
class RNNCell(tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RNNCell, self).__init__()
        self._output_size = 15
        self._state_size = 15

    def __call__(self, X, prev_state):

        network = X
        # ------ 2 convolutional layers ------
        network = tflearn.layers.conv_2d(network, 5, [1, 3], activation='relu', weights_init=tflearn.initializations.variance_scaling(), padding="valid", regularizer=None)
        width = network.get_shape()[2]
        network = tflearn.layers.conv_2d(network, 20, [1, width], [1, 1], activation='relu', weights_init=tflearn.initializations.variance_scaling(), padding="valid", regularizer=None)

        # ------ concatenate the previous state ------
        _, height, width, features = network.get_shape()
        network = tf.reshape(network, [-1, int(height), 1, int(width * features)])
        network = tf.concat([network, prev_state[..., None, None]], axis=3)

        # ------ last convolution and softmax ------
        network = tflearn.layers.conv_2d(network, 1, [1, 1], activation='relu', weights_init=tflearn.initializations.variance_scaling(), padding="valid", regularizer=None)
        network = network[:, :, 0, 0]
        predictions = tflearn.layers.core.activation(network, activation="softmax")

        return predictions, predictions

    @property
    def output_size(self):
        return self._output_size
    @property
    def state_size(self):
        return self._state_size
```

Comment: The sequence length is 100?

Comment: Correct, the windows have 100 time periods. I am also experimenting with those, but they don't seem to break everything.

Comment: It'd be great if you provide the full code and some data to make it reproducible

Comment: I'd love to, but the full code is too long (it includes preprocessing of the data directly in TF and another entire object to pipe the data). I can show you the `RNNCell`, that's compact enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are facing vanished gradients problem.

Potentially the instability can be caused by using ReLU in a combination with a pretty small number of parameters to tune. As far as I understand from the description there are only `1x3x5 = 15` trainable parameters in a first layer for instance. If to suppose, that the initialization is around zero, than gradients of in average 50% of parameters will always stay zero. Generally speaking ReLU on small networks in an evil, especially in a case of RNNs.

1. Try to use Leaky ReLU (but you can face exploding gradients though)
2. Try to use tanh, but check initial values of parameters, that they are really around zero, otherwise your gradients will vanish very quickly as well.
3. Retrieve results of untrained, but just initialized network at a step 0. With a right initialization and NN construction you should get normally distributed values around .5 If you have strictly ones, zeros or mix of them, your NN architecture is wrong. All values strictly .5 is also bad.
4. Consider more robust approach such as LSTM

Comment: I seem to have gaussians centered in zero, not 0.5. Do you think this is the problem? See http://tflearn.org/initializations/#variance-scaling: the distribution is a truncated normal centered in zero `truncated_normal(shape, 0.0, stddev=sqrt(factor / n))`

Comment: Does this explain why Adam doesn't work and Adagrad does?

Comment: Your output should be around .5, because after initialization value before softmax should be around 0. It is hard to judge if your initialization is correct. The easiest test: run the model without training and check the output? Strictly 1/0 - initialization with too big values, .5 - initialization with too small values.
It can explain why some optimizers doesn't work. Some can be more robust to the vanishing gradient problem, but it depends from the implementation.
It also explains why do you need to make huge steps, your gradients are tiny, without a large step you can't converge.

Comment: So it turns out tflearn `variance_scaling()` was initializing most of the weigths with negative values. I'll open an issue on github, because it looks like a bug to me.